# List index out of range on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

I'm getting the 'List index out of range' error when trying to get my NRF24L01 module working on Raspberry Pi 3b+. The code is written in python and I just can't seem to notice the error.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from lib_nrf24 import NRF24
import time
import spidev

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

pipes = [[0xE8, 0xE8, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xE1], [0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xE1]]

radio = NRF24 (GPIO, spidev.SpiDev())
radio.begin(0, 17)

radio.setPayloadSize (32)
radio.setChannel(0x76)
radio.setDataRate(NRF24.BR_1MBPS)
radio.setPALevel(NRF24.PA_MIN)

radio.setAutoAck(True)
radio.enableDynamicPayloads()
radio.enableAckPayload()

radio.openReadingPipe(1, pipes[1])
radio.printDetails()
radio.startListening()
while True :

    while not radio.available(0):
       time.sleep(1/100)

    a = []
    b = []
    receivedMessage = []
    radio.read(receivedMessage, radio.getDynamicPayloadSize())
    a = receivedMessage[0]
    b = receivedMessage[1]
    print( "Temperature:" , a, "Humidity:" , b )
```

The error appears on lines `a = receivedMessage[0]` and `b = receivedMessage[1]`.
Would love some fresh look and advices on how to fix this.
Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/NRF24L01/VEIIIK.py", line 34, in <module>
    a = receivedMessage[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

UPDATE
Using the line `print(radio.read(receivedMessage, radio.getDynamicPayloadSize()))` gives the ouptut:

```
0
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
```

While the line `print(receivedMessage)` outputs `[]`.

Comment: I would imagine the answer is somewhere in the `lib_nrf24` docs; either `radio.read` is supposed to return a value that you check, or it pokes values into the `receivedMessage` argument. If the latter, you should be checking that values are actually added, instead of blindly reading into an empty list.

Comment: What error message? What do you understand from that error, and what have you done to solve it?

Comment: From the error I understand that the `receivedMessage` list is empty, thus sending the list out of range error. So far, I tried downloading a modified library from a different person and using that instead. It did not solve the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You need to provide a [mre] including the full error message with traceback. But yes your understanding is right, the list is probably empty. For some basic debugging try `print(radio.read(receivedMessage, radio.getDynamicPayloadSize()))` and `print(receivedMessage)`.

Comment: @wjandrea Updated the post with the traceback and prints of `radio.read` and `receivedMessage`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you do:

```
if(receivedMessage):
    a = receivedMessage[0]
    b = receivedMessage[1]
    print( "Temperature:" , a, "Humidity:" , b )
```

This might solve the problem.

Comment: That indeed fixed the error. Thank you very much :)

Comment: It solves because in some cases the program is trying to read data from a variable that is null (doesn't exist). To fix you check first if it exists and then reads.

Comment: If variable is null and try to access it `data[0]` you get `index out of range` error.